# Does the number of lines of code have an impact on the whole compilation time in C++?

Tags: c++, compilation

I am wondering if there is correlation between the number of line of code and compilation time by C++ compiler. I am developing a project that has 40k lines with comments for 200k lines in total and I am wondering if cleaning up these comments will speed up the compilation process?

Comment: Probably a little bit, but it's not much work for a parser to ignore comments.  Comments in code are a good thing (unless they just state exactly what you already know what's going on) so leave them in.

Comment: If you have a doubt ,why not measuring it? Writing a code to eliminate all comments and create a new file is rather easy. But I agree the impact should be hardly noticeable

Comment: Fundamentally, all text in a file is read by the compiler.  The more text you have, the more time will expended.  Comments and whitespace are ignored by the compiler, so this is the minimal time expended.  Actual code adds a layer of processing with adds time to the compilation.  Optimization will add more time to the build.  So, keep your comments.

Comment: One of easiest methods to speed up a build is to divide your program into smaller pieces.  This will help reduce changes to the fewest files.  The build process can then only compile the files that have changed.  If your build is very time consuming, run it overnight; or go on a walk.